# pycharm code completion doesn't work for file not in project directory

Tags: pycharm

I dragged and dropped a new file from another directory that isn't in the current project directory. Pycharm doesn't give suggestion/code completion while I type something

[image: A screenshot for the reference]

I was trying to import time, it usually suggests when I'm writing a file in the project directory. Is there any way without adding any additional plugins(my pycharm is already slow) to get this working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons for this not to work.

First, check if code completion is turned on. Go to `File->Settings->Editor->General->Code Completion` and see if there is checkmark next to `Show suggestions as you type` . If there is no checkmark, check it and see if code completion works.

[image: Code completion suggestions]

If that didn't work, maybe `Power Save Mode` is turned on. From PyCharm documentation:

> The Power Save Mode is on (File | Power Save Mode). Turning it on minimizes power consumption of your laptop by eliminating the background operations, including error highlighting, on-the-fly inspections, and code completion.

If that doesn't help, you can read about code completion in PyCharm [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/auto-completing-code.html).

Comment: The Power save mode is off and also the code completion is checked. I couldn't find Code Completion in the Setting for New Projects. I don't know whether I'm looking at the right options or not. But anyway thank you for responding.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing the extension from ".PY" to ".py" and using underscores instead of spaces. Also make sure the file is under your content root, which is under preferences -> project structure